# Syntax error when moving Wordpress Site

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, syntax-error

I recently tried to migrate a Wordpress site from a development server over to a live server. I moved all the contents of the site, imported the database and connected the database via the wp-config file.

Unfortunately however I am getting the error...

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/public_html/corp/wp-content/plugins/page-builder-pmc-shortcode-mundos/classes/class-aq-page-builder.php on line 1
```

I have checked the 'class-aq-page-builder.php' and compared it to a new version of that file but there seems to be no difference between files.

How I might track this down or solve this error?

I have included the first few lines from the 'class-aq-page-builder.php' file below:

```
<?php
/** 
* AQ_Page_Builder class
*
* The core class that generates the functionalities for the
* Aqua Page Builder. Almost nothing inside in the class should
* be overridden by theme authors
*
* @since forever
**/

if(!class_exists('AQ_Page_Builder')) {
class AQ_Page_Builder {

    public $url = AQPB_DIR;
    public $config = array();
    private $admin_notices;

    /**
     * Stores public queryable vars
     */
    function __construct( $config = array()) {

        $defaults['menu_title'] = __('Page Builder', 'framework');
        $defaults['page_title'] = __('Page Builder', 'framework');
        $defaults['page_slug'] = __('aq-page-builder', 'framework');
        $defaults['debug'] = false;

        $this->args = wp_parse_args($config, $defaults);

        $this->args['page_url'] = esc_url(add_query_arg(
            array('page' => $this->args['page_slug']),
            admin_url( 'themes.php' )
        ));

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Plugin support page is better place to put that question :)

Comment: I wondered if it was somethingto do with the php running on that server.

Comment: It would definatly help if you could paste in the code here, the first few lines so we can see if it could be a php issue.

Comment: Plugin support page? :-/

Comment: <?php
/** 
 * AQ_Page_Builder class
 *
 * The core class that generates the functionalities for the
 * Aqua Page Builder. Almost nothing inside in the class should
 * be overridden by theme authors
 *
 * @since forever
 **/
 
if(!class_exists('AQ_Page_Builder')) {
 class AQ_Page_Builder {
  
  public $url = AQPB_DIR;
  public $config = array();
  private $admin_notices;

Comment: If you first disable the plugin, then delete it. Then re-upload the original zip file and activate do you still get the same error?

Comment: I have tried removing all the comments but it seemed to make no difference. Strange that the error is showing on line 1 :-/

Comment: That's not something I have tried. I will give that a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant just move a wordpress site by copy and pasting. Also exporting and importing Database will cause errors like this.

Use all in one migration plugin. First install a wordpress site in your live server then export a backup from your dev server with the plugin and import same data into live server with the same plugin.

Also replace the domain name with the plugin. For example if your development url www.WordPress.dev and live site www.wordpress.com you should go into plugin settings of all in one migration and replace //www.wordpress.dev to //www.wordpress.com this is very important.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that. Will give that a go and pop back.